# Pytest: Date Object cannot be passed on as parameter to a fixture

Tags: pytest

I have tried to pass on a date object as parameter to a pytest fixture and pick it up in the fixture, using the following code snippet:

```
@pytest.fixture
def getData(request):
    """Variable data query"""
    date = request.param
    #do some data calls (with the provided date)...

@pytest.mark.parametrize("getData", [(date.today())], indirect=["getData"])
def test_data(getData):
    #do some tests with the data...
```

However I am getting error messages such as:

- TypeError: 'datetime.date' object is not subscriptable E
- ValueError: could not convert string to Timestamp

Is "request" only accepting Strings? Is there another possibility to pass on an object (other than a String) that is more complex to a fixture as parameter?

Comment: Please show how you pass the object, and possibly the call stack.

Comment: I have extended the code example.

Comment: Your code example should work. I suspect it is the code not shown that has the problem - a callstack could help.